# How setup a sample custom confirm dialog (modal)

Tags: jquery, html, confirmation

I have this code

```
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="line"><a href="" class="del">x</a></div>
```

I need delete every .line after click on .del, then after that on yes in modal-box, which is shown after I clicked on .del

here is my code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarhov/8tq7H/7/)

but if I click then close the modal-box, then again click on .line, after I click on yes on pseudo confirm dialog, it is removing also the previusly clicked .line.

I know that there are plugins for custom confirmation dialogs, but I need a sample code the accomplish this.

and so, how can I detect only the last clicked .line, and delete only that?

UPD

the pseudo modal will be shown it right corner, after click on "X" -  if anyone did not noticed

UPD 2 with animation gif

so click on the first .line, the modal is showed, I click on close-modal, then I click the last .line, again modal -is showed, in this time I click yes, I want to delete the last .line, but instead  - the first and the last .line divs are removing

[animated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhNUz.gif)

Comment: are you asking how to delete the div.line that is wrapping the a.del that is clicked? Sorry I'm confused what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It seems that everything works

Comment: updated question with animated screenshot

Comment: I see what you are trying to fix now. I updated my answer with a working jsfiddle and code. FYI it is bad practice to put click functions inside of click functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work ([new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8dW4/1/)):

```
var item;

$('.del').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    item = $(this).closest('.line');
    $('.modal').show();
});

$('.yes').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    item.fadeOut();
});

$('.close-modal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').hide();
});
```

Comment: thank you, that's working, but I can't understand why mine was not working...what have I been doing wrong?

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure how yours was working as well as it was. Using the .each() simply loops through each matching element and you were assigning 'item' each time - before the click even happened. Also bad practice to have click statements inside of click statements. Best to handle each element separately.